# Historically informed performance - Tuning

Tags: tuning, strings, history, orchestra

I recently attended a performance of Beethoven's Violin Concerto by Nicola Benedetti and the Orchestra of the Age of Enlightenment under Marin Alsop.  At the end, Nicola played an encore: a version of Auld Lang Syne.  She commented that she was not used to playing the piece on gut strings and at this pitch.  My initial reaction was that since it was a solo piece, why would she feel the need to transpose it rather than play at a familiar pitch.  I then realised that this was probably not what she meant but that her violin was not tuned to the modern standard concert pitch.  Not having perfect pitch, I had not picked up on this.  What is a likely tuning that was used or is that an impossible question and it was a matter of the particular instruments they had or the judgement of the conductor?

Comment: 'Baroque pitch' is widely agreed to be around A=415, a semitone down from today's A=440.  'Beethoven pitch' can be more tricky to pin down.  He seems to have owned a tuning fork at A=455, rather HIGHER than today's standard.  Do we know what pitch  Benedetti and Alsop picked?

Comment: I would like to know what was used in this concert but I am not sure how to find out.  It was only afterwards when I thought about Nicola's comment that the question occurred to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great question - the answer has everything to do with the violin strings.

The performer’s comment about the strings is important, and here’s why:

Contemporary strings are often steel with a nickel-winding around the lower strings. This gives violins their brilliant sound. It also means we can put more tension on them and tune to higher pitch tunings (setting off things like pitch-inflation).

Okay, so what?

The performer was playing on traditional gut strings. These strings are made of organic material. They’re softer, sweeter with richer overtones, and not as brilliant. They also can’t support as much tension (and therefore higher tuning) as their contemporary counterpart. Thus, by our modern ears, are typically played at lower tunings (when in fact historically it has been the other way around!).

This opens up a larger conversation about pitch that goes beyond this question, but historically speaking, in the Baroque and Medieval times, tuning had not been standardized and often tuning would even change from town to town, sometimes making it difficult for musicians to play together. It is for this reason that “A”, now the international tuning note, was usually heard somewhere between 380-416hz - a far cry from our standard 440hz and the sometimes popular 441-443 range.

So, because of the lower tuning frequency, the entire instrument sounds lower, even though it plays the same way. Even if that performer were used to playing on that instrument, the act of switching from contemporary instruments to historical ones can be pretty jarring at first until your ears adjust. It’s likely the violinist tuned to A 380-416hz and gave their comment acknowledging how much lower the violin sounded.

I remember once hearing a  piece by Ben Johnston for just-intonated piano. It sounded really weird to me until my ears adjusted and I heard that was a bluesy sort of shuffle. I had no idea! It was almost like my ears came into focus.

I this answer brings that performance into focus!

Comment: Thanks.  I had expected and picked up on some points e.g. the valveless horns; I rather like the sound of them.  I had forgotten about the possibility that the entire orchestra was at a non-standard (in the modern sense) pitch.  When I realised this, I next guessed that it would have been the period oboes which, as usual, gave the reference for tuning.

Comment: If that was the case, how would the rest of the orchestra have compensated? Is there enough leeway with all the instruments to drop 'concert A' down to that level?

Comment: @Tim - Typically when a guest soloist performs an encore, they're alone. So the rest of the orchestra wouldn't have been an issue. In general, they would use period instruments - all gut strings, natural horns, crumhorns, sackbuts, viol de gamba, harpsichord, etc, so everything would be tuned accordingly, just like a contemporary orchestra.

Comment: @Tim - In the WEIRD case of a modern orchestra specifically, yes, they could theoretically compensate: all strings would tune down, brass would pull out all their valve slides, woodwinds would pull out headjoints, barrels, bocals, and reeds, and the conductor would sag a bit.

Comment: @Tim - Yes, the last part of that was a joke, and yes, I made another comment specifically so I had space for that joke, and yes, I made another comment explicitly explaining that other comment.

Comment: I should have explicitly stated it but it was a period orchestra, not a modern one.  The encore was a solo.  I presume from the comment that  Nicola was using the same instrument as for the concerto.  I assumed, but cannot verify, that she maintained the same tuning.  At the very least, her ability to retune would have limited by the points that jjmusicnotes made.

Comment: And would the conductor use a Bb baton instead of the more usual C...?

Comment: @Tim Transposing instruments are already enough of a nuisance, now you want to introduce transposing batons.  Slightly longer, I guess.

Comment: I once played a HIP performance of Mozart's Clarinet Concerto to a friend with perfect pitch.  She asked whether it was in G.  I said that it was in A and she was puzzled as it sounded like G to her.  I guess that the orchestra was tuned about a tone flat by modern standards.  Unfortunately, she was not present for this performance and I don't have perfect pitch.

Comment: @Tim - Actually a transposing baton, so the conductor would read C, but it comes out Eb.

Comment: @badjohn - Well, if you used a Bb clarinet, you would be reading in "A" but it would have sounded in G; unless you're talking concert pitch, then that would be different. I have a friend with absolute pitch but about a semitone flat, so his perfect "A" is about everyone else' "Ab".

Comment: @jjmusicnotes When I said "played", I meant a CD not my own clarinet.  I presume that the performer was using a clarinet in A so his part would have been written in C.  I will check that tonight.  I have a friend who has perfect pitch but it was gone wrong with age.  Now, he needs to play C# for it to sound like a C to him.  It frustrates him when playing the piano.

Comment: That baton would only work for alter sax parts, surely...

Comment: You can actually tune a violin gut E string up to 440.  Won't last long, but it can and has been done often enough.

Comment: @scottwallace - yes I thought this might come up and debated including it in my answer. Yes with gut strings they *can* be tuned that high but you’ll burn through them and they are much more expensive that steel strings

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - yes indeed.

Comment: @ScottWallace baroque violins are typically set up rather differently: the neck is at a shallower angle and the bridge is lower.  I believe the sounding length of the string is typically a bit shorter, too. In any event, the difference isn't solely due to the strings and the bow.  But some music, especially early baroque, is played at 465 Hz or so, about a whole step higher than 415 Hz.  I don't know whether violinists typically change to lighter strings for that.

Comment: @phoog - I know about Chorton in the early Baroque, but I seriously doubt that violins were ever tuned that high.  Lighter strings don't affect the breaking tension materially.  And the baroque violins I've seen are not appreciably shorter in mensur than modern instruments.

Comment: @ScottWallace I'm not talking about Chorton so much as about Venetian pitch.  Modern string players have also performed Venetian music at A=465.  I don't know how much they changed the setup of their instruments to do it.  Lighter strings give a higher pitch _at the same tension,_ so the breaking tension isn't an issue.  A quick search turned this up, where you can hear a violin tuned to A=465: https://youtube.com/watch?v=Y6D2vpryg3o

Answer (score -5):

The myth that gut strings need to be tuned lower owing to "weakness" has long been disproven: the truth is that gut strings can achieve a higher pitch at lower tension than steel strings. The fact that, at the time, unmodified Baroque instruments strung with gut were able to play along with organs & other keyboard instruments tuned to a pitch well above A=440 would support this - if the "weakness of gut" argument were true, string instruments would have been blowing apart everywhere, which was clearly not the case. Another fact: with the introduction of steel strings in the 18th century, string instruments built before that time needed to be rebuilt & modified to support the greater tension required to tune steel strings to the same pitch the gut strings had been tuned to previously. All of this is well-documented in a brilliant display in the Metropolitain Museum instrument collection.

Comment: "unmodified Baroque instruments strung with gut were able to play along with organs & other keyboard instruments tuned to a pitch well above A=440" - on the face of it, this statement is wrong, as we instead have plenty of examples of the part for the organ being written a tone lower than the other instruments to accomodate the difference in pitch (organ at or about 465 Hz, strings a whole tone lower at around 415 Hz); example in following comment.

Comment: Ex. https://www.bach-digital.de/rsc/viewer/BachDigitalSource_derivate_00059566/db_bachst0046_pa051.jpg (cello/low string part to Bach's BWV 147; notated in C major); https://www.bach-digital.de/rsc/viewer/BachDigitalSource_derivate_00059570/db_bachst0046_pa059.jpg (continuo part for the same, in Bb major). In any case, this late answer does not even answer the OP's question.

Comment: Hi, I think a source of the initial statement would help to make this answer more credible!

Comment: @AlexJ while that is true, it is also true on the other hand that Venetian strings played in the same notated pitch as organs and brass.  The pitch of a string depends not only on its tension but also on its mass, as even a casual glance at the G and E strings of a violin can show.  Instead of increasing the tension by a certain factor, you can decrease the mass by the same factor.

Comment: @Tom string frequency for a given length depends on tension and linear density (which, for a given length, depends on mass); steel is denser than gut, QED.  Steel violin strings are only about 100 years old, by the way -- most classical music was written for gut strings.

Comment: @phoog I was not talking about that, but about that the statement has long been disproven.. When? By who? [reference needed]

Comment: @phoog Also, gut is lighter, yes but what also matters is how much tension you can put. If you have to tension it 10x less (say, as an extreme case) the fact that it is 2x lighter (say again) won't compensate entirely.

Comment: @phoog For the sake of argument, "same notated pitch" does not imply that the instruments were actually tuned to the same pitch; historical sources do describe the usage of transposition by professional performers in practice, as well as simultaneous use of instruments tuned to different reference pitches (for ex. https://www.historicbrass.org/edocman/hbj-1994/HBSJ_1994_JL01_006_Haynes.pdf; an example in Bach is the oboe in the opening aria of BWV 132, notated in the score a minor third above the other instruments; https://www.bach-digital.de/receive/BachDigitalWork_work_00000162).

Comment: I'll admit that Bach's organ being a tone off (and this being reflected in the parts, prepared for such specific performances, which AFAIK had minimal rehearsal time: Bach's music is hard enough as is without transposing on sight) might be a very specific example, but the question of historical pitch is in any case a very complex one and not something which can be answered here in a few short lines. If you're not already aware of it, https://www.earlymusicsources.com/youtube/historical-pitch is a good starting point.

Comment: @AlexJ I mean that strings and voices and winds are playing the same pieces at the same time in the same keys.  Yes it's possible that the string players were transposing at sight, but it is not likely.  The Early Music Sources video confirms my point: they were using higher pitch in Venice.  Since they were clearly playing violins there, it is clearly possible to tune gut-strung violins to A=465 Hz.

Comment: @Tom yes, but my point is that a citation should not be needed to explain that tuning a gut-strung violin from A=392 to A=465 does not have to increase the tension because one can use different strings on the instrument.

Comment: So we agree, that's not the point I was asking a citation about :). When I see something like "has long been disproven" on a subject that seems controversial, I cannot help asking. If it is the case that should be easy to justify.